# check image selected or not in PHP

Tags: php, image, validation

I have a form to upload image like below

```
<form  name="sample" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2048000" />
Select an Image: <input name="photo" id="photo" type="file" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Now i have to check something like below ..

```
If(any file/image selected){
i will check here whether the selected file is a valid image.
}
```

I have managed the validation part for if but what i can not check is whether any file is selected or not.
I used the following condition

```
if(!empty($_FILES))
```

But this execute in all cased whether someone select a file or not.

Please someone help me how can i make this work.

Here is my full PHP code:

```
<?php
// Do not show notice errors
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


if(!empty($_FILES)) // Has the image been uploaded?
{
include 'config.php';

$file = $_FILES['image_file'];

$file_name = $file['name'];

$error = ''; // Empty

// Get File Extension (if any)

$ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, "."), 1));

// Check for a correct extension. The image file hasn't an extension? Add one

   if($validation_type == 1)
   {
   $file_info = getimagesize($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']);

      if(empty($file_info)) // No Image?
      {
      $error .= "The uploaded file doesn't seem to be an image.";
      }
      else // An Image?
      {
      $file_mime = $file_info['mime'];

         if($ext == 'jpc' || $ext == 'jpx' || $ext == 'jb2')
         {
         $extension = $ext;
         }
         else
         {
         $extension = ($mime[$file_mime] == 'jpeg') ? 'jpg' : $mime[$file_mime];
         }

         if(!$extension)
         {
         $extension = '';  
         $file_name = str_replace('.', '', $file_name); 
         }
      }
   }
   else if($validation_type == 2)
   {
      if(!in_array($ext, $image_extensions_allowed))
      {
      $exts = implode(', ',$image_extensions_allowed);
      $error .= "You must upload a file with one of the following extensions: ".$exts;
      }

      $extension = $ext;
   }

   if($error == "") // No errors were found?
   {
   $new_file_name = strtolower($file_name);
   $new_file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);
   $new_file_name = substr($new_file_name, 0, -strlen($ext));
   $new_file_name .= $extension;

   // File Name
   $move_file = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_image_to_folder.$new_file_name);

   if($move_file)
       {
       $done = 'The image has been uploaded.';
       }
   }
   else
   {
   @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
   }

   $file_uploaded = true;
}

?>
```

Please check the code now. I just need to change the line

```
if(!empty($_FILES))
```

such that if someone select any file then if condition will be true but if they don't select any file i.e if they keep the field blank then if condition will be false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also check like:

```
if(isset($_FILES['photo']) && !empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) { 
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
 // Your code....
}
```

If you want to be more specific for exactly file not selected issue, you can use `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` constant as well.

You can find further information from here.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Put your PHP code to your question. Just Edit it with that. Then we can check.

Comment: Please check the code now. I just need to change the line if(!empty($_FILES)) such that if someone select any file then if condition will be true but if they don't select any file i.e if they keep the field blank then if condition will be false

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You have to replace `file` as `photo`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
isset($_FILES['photo']) && isset($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
```

Also you should check whether the uploaded file is a real image, you can do this with [getImageSize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of the image.

Comment: Try var_dump($_FILES) to figure out whats actually sent by your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try :

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
```

... for the mime_type better use finfo if available.

Comment: The condition or the retrieving the file_type using finfo?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
{
    $mimetype = mime_content_type($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    if(in_array($mimetype, array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'))) {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '/images/' . $_FILES['photo']['name']);
   echo 'OK';
     } else {
             echo 'Not an image file!';
     }
}
```

Comment: Using mime_content_type is misleading ... better use fileinfo functions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DemoUser

if(isset($_FILES['photo']) && !empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) { }

works just perfect